# positive lower bound of $\tanh t -\tanh (t/(1+a)),0<a<1$

Tags: inequality

I am looking for a positive lower bound for $f(t)=\tanh t -\tanh (t/(1+a)),0<a<1,t\geq 0$.

I expect to find that:

$$f(t)\geq a g(t),\qquad g(t)>0\tag{1}$$.

What does the $g(t)$ look like?

Thanks-
mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $t>0$. By the mean value theorem
$$
\tanh t-\tanh\frac{t}{1+a}=\Bigl(t-\frac{t}{1+a}\Bigr)\frac{1}{\cosh^2 s},\quad \frac{t}{1+a}<s<t.
$$
Since $\cosh t$ is increasing, we get
$$
\tanh t-\tanh\frac{t}{1+a}\ge\frac{a}{1+a}\,\frac{t}{\cosh^2t}.
$$

Comment: Julian:  Thanks a lot for the answer!  I could also use $t>\tanh t$ if I want to express the lower bound in terms of $e^t$. Right?

Comment: Yes, you could.